# How to add a class to Laravel next and previous pagination links

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using the built in Laravel 5.2 pagination with the `->render()` function to output the pagination links. I need to add a class to the next and previous links in order to style them. Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change pagination links style just a little bit (for example, just change some colors), easiest way to do that is overriding some of the `pagination` related CSS classes. For example, you can add this code to your CSS file and see how links style will be changed:

```
.pagination>li>a, .pagination>li>span {
    color: #6db91c;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.pagination>li>a:hover, .pagination>li>span:hover, .pagination>li>a:focus, .pagination>li>span:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #6db91c;
    border-color: #6db91c
}

.pagination>.active>a, .pagination>.active>span, .pagination>.active>a:hover, .pagination>.active>span:hover, .pagination>.active>a:focus, .pagination>.active>span:focus {
    z-index: 2;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #6db91c;
    border-color: #6db91c
}

.pagination>.disabled>span, .pagination>.disabled>span:hover, .pagination>.disabled>span:focus, .pagination>.disabled>a, .pagination>.disabled>a:hover, .pagination>.disabled>a:focus {
    color: #000; background-color: #fff; border-color: #000; cursor: not-allowed
}
```

If you don't want to do that for some reason, you can [create custom pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator).

Comment: Yeah I can't do it that way though because there is no backwards compatible way to target just the first and last li that why I need to add a class to them

Comment: In this case, you need to create pagination manually: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator -- Also, look at `Additional Helper Methods` I think they will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

for front end css framework like i use [bulma](http://bulma.io) i simply create jQuery Dom select pagination child li and add class pagination-link example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Setting Pagination Bulma Class
    $('.pagination>li').addClass("pagination-link");

});
```